# Recover original Procedure after modification in Oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle12c, recover

I inadvertently changed a stored procedure in Oracle 12c. 
Is there a way to recover the original version of Procedure? 
I have normal export backup of Entire Data base of previous days.

Comment: How was the backup created?

Comment: It was created using normal export command "exp".

Answer (score 1):

You can use

`as of timestamp systimestamp - interval '<int>' [year|month|day|hour|minute|second]` syntax for `user_source` view :

```
select s.text
  from user_source
  as of timestamp systimestamp - interval '1' day s
 where upper(s.name)='MYPROC'
   and s.type = 'PROCEDURE'
 order by s.line;
```

which returns  the data of the day before having the same *hour:minute:second* combination with the current time provided the value of `undo_retention` DB paremeter is big enough to hold the data of the time point in the past. (For this case, the value should be `86400`(*in second*) at least)

Comment: I got error 'ORA-01555: snapshot too old: rollback segment number 10 with name "_SYSSMU10_2767132874$" too small'. I tried for interval '5' days and replaced 'MYPROC' with the Procedure name I am trying to recover.

Comment: to recover your data, undo_retention should be at least 5*86400=432000, and it's yet not guaranteed even the value is big enough, depends on undo segment's operating style @AnilKumar . In this case, consult your backups and import to an auxiliary server.